# Computational complexity of deciding isomorphism of rational polyhedral cones

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $C,C'$ be rational polyhedral cones in $\mathbb R^n$ both with non-empty interior. Rational means they are generated by vectors with rational entries. One says that $C,C'$ are *isomorphic* if there is a unimodular integer matrix $A\in Gl(n,\mathbb Z)$ such that $AC=C'$.

> > **Question.** What is the computational complexity of deciding whether $C,C'$ are isomorphic?  I'm happy to consider either that the cones are given by finite generating sets (say with integer entries) or by defining inequalities (say over $\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the abstract of "[On the complexity of polytope isomorphism problems](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106093)",

> [W]e derive that the problems to decide whether two polytopes, given either by vertex or by facet descriptions, are projectively or affinely isomorphic, are graph isomorphism hard.

Skimming the proof of Theorem 3, I think it should also establish that your problem is GI-Hard.

This paper has [6 citations in MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?refcit=1996205&loc=refcit), none of which appear to address this issue, so it is possible that this is the state of the art.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not an expert in this area, I am confident this should be poly-time solvable. Look at Chapter 4 in 'Theory of Linear and Integer Programming' by A. Schrijver. The unimodular equivalence you defined can be uniquely characterized by Hermite's normal form. Thus, you only need to convert both $C$ amd $C^{\prime}$ to Hermite's normal form and check whether they are equal.

Comment: I will take a look. You are saying to cones are equivalent iff the corresponding matrices have the same Hermite normal form?

Comment: Almost. In the book it is stated for the integer lattice induced by $Ax=b$; considering inequalities instead can be tricky.
But since you only care about cones you can consider the matrices induced by a Hilbert basis instead. Then Corollary 4.3a should do the job.

Comment: The cone might not be pointed, so there may not be a hilbert basis.

Comment: I am not so convinced here. The Hermite form seems to have to do with generating the same lattice. I am asking for isomorphic cones. I don't see that this is the same as checking the Hermite form for a matrix. Can you give details?

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Now I realize my answer is far from solving the problem.

I still want to fix it somehow, so let me try. First, every rational polyhedral cone $C$ is generated by a Hilbert basis. If $C$ is pointed then a minimal basis is unique.

So, in the pointed case, let $A_C$, $A_{C^{\prime}}$ whose columns are given by the minimal Hilbert basis of $C$, $C^{\prime}$, respectively. You can verify whether these matrices are unimod. equivalent by taking their HNF. This only proves they generate the same lattice, but perhaps from here you can prove the isomorphism for the cones.

Comment: This is the tricky part to do in a way with reasonable complexity.